# Set constraints in a Matrix - OPTIM in R

Tags: r, matrix, nonlinear-optimization

I have a vector of integers as input values (starting values for optim par)

```
my.data.var <- c(10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
             10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
             10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
             10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)
```

- Optimization problem is a min. problem.
- The error function calculates sum of square root of diff in values between
  TWO MATRICES (Given Values Matrix vs Calculated Matrix)
- The calculated matrix is the one that uses above integer vector.
  Hence, in the error function, I stack the integer vector into a
  matrix as `my.data.var.mat <- matrix(my.data.var,nrow = 4,ncol = 6,byrow = TRUE)`

The constraint that I must introduce is that `colSum(my.data.var.mat) <=1`

The optim is defined as

```
sols<-optim(my.data.var,Error.func,method="L-BFGS-B",upper=c(Inf,1,1,1,1,1,Inf,1,1,1,1,1,Inf,1,1,1,1,1,Inf,1,1,1,1,1),
  lower=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Error Function is defined as

```
Error.func <- function(my.data.var){


my.data.var.mat <- matrix(my.data.var,nrow = ncol(my.data.matrix.prod),ncol = ncol(my.data.matrix.inj)+1,byrow = TRUE)

  Calc.Qjk.Value <- Qjk.Cal.func(my.data.timet0,my.data.qo,my.data.matrix.time,
                                 my.data.matrix.inj, my.data.matrix.prod,my.data.var,my.data.var.mat)

  diff.values <- my.data.matrix.prod-Calc.Qjk.Value    #FIND DIFFERENCE BETWEEN CAL. MATRIX AND ORIGINAL MATRIX

  Error <- ((colSums ((diff.values^2), na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1))/nrow(my.data.matrix.inj))^0.5    #sum of square root of the diff

  Error_total <- sum(Error,na.rm=FALSE)/ncol(my.data.matrix.prod)   # total avg error

  Error_total
}
```

Given Dataset: `my.data.matrix.prod` , `my.data.timet0, my.data.qo, my.data.matrix.time, my.data.matrix.inj`

So, my question is how and where should I introduce the matrix col sum constraint? Or the other way to put it as how would OPTIM vary integer vector under Matrix col sum constraint?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: thnks. hope I get some advice !

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Trying my luck with "nloptr". lets see!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Solved it. Instead of using Optim, I used nloptr solver. It allows for inequality constraints. have a look here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951719/multiple-inequality-constraints-minimization-with-r-nloptr-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that `nloptr` is a better option than `optim` since my problem consisted of "inequality constraints".

I modified the implementation as I explain in this post here. ["multiple inequality constraints" - Minimization with R nloptr package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951719/multiple-inequality-constraints-minimization-with-r-nloptr-package)

Hence, closing this thread.